# Call default constructor of a S4 by class name

Tags: r, r-s4

Are there more ways to call a function by name like I do below via do.call?

```
setClass(Class = "MyClass",
         representation = representation(name = "character",
                                         type = "character"
         )
)
MyClass <- function(...) new("MyClass",...)
cC<-"MyClass"
do.call(cC,list())
```

Comment: @SimonO101 Loosely speaking I have a config file from where I read Class Names like MyClass and want to create an Object of class MyClass by this String.

Comment: OK, so I don't understand why you don't just use `new("MyClass",...)`? I think I am not getting something.

Comment: Because It looks nicer if you call your Object by name like `a<-MyClass()` or `b<-list()`.

Comment: `setClass` returns a generator function so no need to create one of your own and no need to call the generator function by a new name, so the common ways are `MyClass <- setClass(Class = "MyClass", representation = representation(name = "character", type = "character")); MyClass(); do.call("MyClass",  list())`

Comment: @MartinMorgan Many thx you are completly right, I got this strategy from [here](http://www.stamats.de/S4KlassenUndMethoden.R)

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
cstor <- get(cC)
cstor()
```